# Why ($e^x$)'s derivative i.e. $e^x$ , not equal to $(a^x )$'s derivative while $a$ is any number and $e$ is a number as well?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Why ($e^x$)'s derivative i.e. $e^x$ , not equal to ($a^x$ )'s derivative while $a$ is any number and $e$ is any number as well?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  The derivative of $a^x$ with respect to $x$ is $  a^x\ln a$, and $\ln e=1$

Comment: Because $e$ is the unique number such that ${e^x}'=e^x$.

Comment: If you compute the derivative of $a^x$ the answer is $a^x$  multiplied by an annoying constant. But there is a special value of $a$ for which that "annoying constant" is equal to $1$.

Comment: $e$ is not any number, it is *the* number for which $(e^x)' = e^x$.

Comment: OP doesn't know the meaning of number $e=2.71\cdots$ and you give him full downvotes. You selfish pedants

Comment: Thank you for the intuition! @littleO

Answer (score 2):

Let $y=e^x$. Then $x=\ln y$. Taking the derivative of both sides with respect to $x$ yields $$\frac{dx}{dx}=\frac{d(\ln y)}{dx}$$ so $$1=\frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{dx}$$ and finally we obtain $$\frac{dy}{dx}=y=e^x.$$ Therefore, $$\frac{d}{dx}e^x=e^x.$$ This is the only number that satisfies this property, since $y=e^x$ gives us $x=\ln y$. If $y=2^x$, for example, $x$ would be a nasty $\log_2 y$, and when we take this derivative, it will not be as nice.